# Why isn't this createing the images

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I'm currently trying to make it so this array displays the aliens that are part of the array but for some reason when I call the function as part of my game loop nothing appears and I'm quite stumped :/

//Setting array for alien pictures.
var AliArray = new Array();

```
var Init = function (){

    var totalRows = 12; //How many rows of aliens to spawn  
    var totalCols = 12; //How many cols of aliens to spawn  
    // For loops that creates the multidemensional array [col][row]
    for (q = 0; q < 12; q++) {
        AliArray[q] = new Array();
    }
    var imgWidth = 50; // Defines image's width 
    var imgHeight = 18; // defines image's height
    var rng = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); // Gives a random number so that it spawns different aliens once level is complete.
    for (var row = 0; row < totalRows; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < totalCols; col++) {
            AliArray[row][col] = new Image();
            var x = col * imgWidth;
            var y = row * imgHeight;
            AliArray[row][col].onload = drawAliens(AliArray, row, col, x, y);
            if (rng < 5) {
                AliArray[row][col].src = "images/alien1.png";
            }
            else if (rng > 5) {
                AliArray[row][col].src = "images/alien2x.png";
            }
            else {
                AliArray[row][col].src = "images/alien3.png";
            }
        }
    }
};

var drawAliens = function (AliArray, row, col, x, y) {
    return function () {
        ctx.drawImage(AliArray[row][col], x, y);
    }
};
```

any feedback would be brilliant, as I can't quite workout as to why it's not currently loading the images. The most I've managed to get it to do is load the images but they instantly disappear or go behind the canvas even when in the right order.

Comment: Are you sure you enter the function? Try adding a  console.log("I am debugging"); or an alert(); inside the function just to see if the function is indeed called. Then Next best guess is if it isn't drawing maybe there is nothing to draw? check if the array containing the alians is empty?

Comment: Ahh you are correct for some reason the array seems to not actually hold anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to past this code in a new html page, then change the path reference of image, seems work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <script>

   var c = document.getElementById('c');
   var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
   var AliArray = [];
   var Init = function () {

   var totalRows = 12; //How many rows of aliens to spawn  
   var totalCols = 12; //How many cols of aliens to spawn  
   // For loops that creates the multidemensional array [col][row]
   for (q = 0; q < 12; q++) {
    AliArray[q] = new Array();
   }
   var imgWidth = 50; // Defines image's width 
   var imgHeight = 18; // defines image's height
   var rng = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); // Gives a random number so that it spawns different aliens once level is complete.
   for (var row = 0; row < totalRows; row++) {
   for (var col = 0; col < totalCols; col++) {
     AliArray[row][col] = new Image();
     var x = col * imgWidth;
     var y = row * imgHeight;
       AliArray[row][col].onload = drawAliens(AliArray, row, col, x, y);
       AliArray[row][col].src = "baby gator logo.jpg";
   }
  }
 };

 var drawAliens = function (AliArray, row, col, x, y) {
 return function () {
   ctx.drawImage(AliArray[row][col], x, y);
 }
};

Init();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understand that the code works just not sure as to why when put into context it suddenly no longer produces it's intent :/